# How do I resolve a code error on a script?

Tags: r

I am trying add a `month` column and wrote the following script:

```r
df$month <- format(as.Date(df$date), '%m')
```

I got this error:

> attempt to use zero-length variable name.

How can I fix this, please!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

can you post some example data on which your working. This way I can help you better to replicate & resolve your error.

I did following check, below is test dataset which has blanks & NAs in the date column. I checked your code on it and it seem to be working fine.

```
data<- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), admi_number = c(1,2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                      admission = c("2014-04-16", "2014-05-22","2014-12-20", "2014-12-18", NA, "2014-06-01", "","2015-01-01"),
                      discharge = c("2014-06-27", "2014-04-16", "2014-12-21","2014-12-23", "2014-01-06", "2014-06-10", "2015-01-10", "")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

format(as.Date(data$admission), '%m')
```

below is the result

[image]

Note here, the as.Date function usually work right when date column is in format %Y-%m-%d, else not. Please check this once.

Comment: I have given the sample dataset above in my code, you can replicate it. Please replicate and check.

Comment: Did you see my image? The values have date and time like this: "2020-06-12 15:42:35", should I replicate with date only or with date and time?

Comment: Oh the image is not visible pancaldi. As per the format you have mentions with DATE+TIME it should work fine. Like this, format(as.Date("2020-06-12 15:42:35"), format = '%m') this will give you result as "06". So I suggest you to instead of image put some example date, As the error is still untraceable.

Comment: I see, too bad you couldn't see the image. Maybe I didn't upload it well. See below:           start_time                         end_time                                                                                                        "2020-06-05 12:15:09"     "2020-06-05  15:15:45"

Comment: It's still not visible. If your trying to upload the image here in comments it wont work, try to add it by editing your question itself. Also does the example I gave you does not resolve your problem ?

Comment: I see, too bad you couldn't see the image. Maybe I didn't upload it well. See below :           start_time                                  end_time                                                                                                        "2020-06-05 12:15:09"     "2020-06-05  15:15:45"                                                               "2021-04-10 19:00:00"     "2021-04-10  19:31:01"                                                             There are thousand of rows on each column dating from May 2020 to April 2021.

Comment: One more question: how do you think I should format a column with date and time, so I can use it for calculations later?

Comment: use as.POSIXct() or as.POSIXlt() to turn it into the date+time format understand by the system R. This way it will be more use full for further calculation. If possible upvote the answer